# Trying to insert negative decimals in mysql 5.5

Tags: mysql, insert, decimal

I try to insert negative decimal numbers in mysql 5.5 but without any luck I've been trying altering column as `DECIMAL(5,2)` but doesn't work in my case (Exmpl. value  -24.83)

**table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE `tracker_master` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `prog_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prod_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prod_id` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `qty` tinyint(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prod_wert` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `best_wert` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `verguetung` double(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lp_id` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `produkt_klicks` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,

  `o_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `query` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `beste_nr` (`best_nr`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=639163 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

targeted column `prod_wert`

the query string is dynamically created with php. If I replace minus then the query is working

I've been making a trick on value what I read out from CSV

```
 else if ($i==15) /// best_nr
                            $csv_line[15] = ($csv_line[15] > 0 ) ? $csv_line[15] : 0;
```

in this case the query works but I want to have those negative value

Comment: Could you give a description of your table, plus the query you are using :)

Comment: You'll need to show the PHP too, and perhaps the string it generates if you can echo it, because it's a dynamically generated SQL string so we need to see what SQL it generates.

Comment: FIRST AF ALL GET RID OF DOUBLE !

Comment: what is result of inserting -24.83 into DECIMAL(5,2) ?

Comment: chceck id DECIMAL isn't UNSIGNED

Comment: DECIMAL(5,2) not UNSIGNED won't work